# Separate double responses into separate factor levels

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
DF <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c("Option 1", "Option 1", "Option 1, Option 2", "Option 2", "Option 2", "Option 1, Option 2")),
                  ID1 = factor(c("Resp1", "Resp1", "Resp3", "Resp4", "Resp5", "Resp6")))
```

I want to separate the double responses, so that I only have "Option 1" and "Option 2" levels, with the double responses assigned to both. One option is to rename the levels and then use `separate_rows`, but it's pretty labor-heavy:

```
levels(DF$V1)
levels(DF$V1)[levels(DF$V1)=="Option 1"] <- "Option1"
levels(DF$V1)[levels(DF$V1)=="Option 2"] <- "Option2"
levels(DF$V1)[levels(DF$V1)=="Option 1, Option 2"] <- "Option1, Option2"
DF_result <- DF %>%
  separate_rows(V1) %>%
  mutate(V1 = factor(V1))
DF_result
```

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drop your first few lines where you replace values (e.g. "Option 1" --> "Option1"), because `separate_rows` takes a `sep` argument that you can set to just a comma. Since some of your values have spaces between "Option" and the number, and some do not, you can remove all the spaces to standardize them—I'm using `stringr::str_remove_all` because it's convenient. Then separate the rows by commas, then make your factor.

```r
library(tidyverse)

DF %>% 
  mutate(V1 = str_remove_all(V1, " ")) %>%
  separate_rows(V1, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(V1 = as.factor(V1))
#>        V1   ID1
#> 1 Option1 Resp1
#> 2 Option1 Resp1
#> 3 Option1 Resp3
#> 4 Option2 Resp3
#> 5 Option2 Resp4
#> 6 Option2 Resp5
#> 7 Option1 Resp6
#> 8 Option2 Resp6
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I would actually leave `separate_rows(V1, sep = ",") %>%` out, but it's obviously personal preference.

Comment: @KaC Without `separate_rows`, you're not separating rows with multiple options. That was however one of the requirements as per your problem statement.

Comment: Yeah I'm confused too. I thought the point was to separate the rows...?

Comment: Sorry. A typo. I meant the line above.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to first apply `tidyr::separate_rows` and then remove the space from `V1` column using `gsub`. Please ensure to pass `sep = ","` to `separate_rows` function to avoid any pre-processing on `V1`.

```
library(tidyverse)

DF %>% separate_rows(V1, sep = ",") %>%    
mutate(V1 = gsub("(Option)\\s+(\\d+)","\\1\\2", V1))

    ID1       V1
1 Resp1  Option1
2 Resp1  Option1
3 Resp3  Option1
4 Resp3  Option2
5 Resp4  Option2
6 Resp5  Option2
7 Resp6  Option1
8 Resp6  Option2
```

Comment: This works. Thank you. I would actually leave `mutate(V1 = gsub("(Option)\\s+(\\d+)","\\1\\2", V1))` out, but it's obviously personal preference.

Comment: @KaC Since, you got few items as `Option 1` and few as `Option1`. Hence, you need to make them equal. Just `separate_rows` will not be sufficient. Moreover, I thought to replace `space` before `separate_rows` but it looked to me a bit more risky as I'm not aware about your actual data and how many other options.

Comment: My bad. I only now realize there are some typos in my code. I ran yours after apparently correcting mine in R. I’ll fix the code when I’m back on the computer later today.